# Roof moss removal?

Tags: roof, moss

My roof has developed clumps of moss in some areas (photos at : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCvsa.jpg). The roof itself is 12 years old.

I just bought the house a year ago, so am wondering whether this moss needs to be professionally removed tile by tile? Or do you think it will just die away by the end of summer? Thanks!

Comment: It won't just die, no. But whether you need to get it professionally removed or just do it yourself depends mostly on your tolerance for heights.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the moss. You should also trim that tree so it isn’t on your roof, and you should empty the gutters too.